# Manual implementation of Standard Deviation with NSExpression

Tags: ios, core-data, nsexpression

It looks like the standard deviation method for `Core Data` on iOS does not exists, so I'm trying to do it by hand.

I'm just starting with `NSExpression` so I'm struggling with this:

```
let numbers = [4, -2]
let numbersExpr = NSExpression(forConstantValue: numbers)

let avgExpr = NSExpression(forFunction: "average:", arguments: [numbersExpr])
let subExpr = NSExpression(forFunction: "from:subtract:", arguments: [numbersExpr, avgExpr])

let v = subExpr.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil)
```

In my `subExpr` I'm trying to subtract the average to all the values of my numbers array, but it crashes when trying to evaluate v on the last line.

How to do that with `NSExpressions`?

Answer (score 0):

It's `subExpr` that crashes:

```
let subExpr = NSExpression(forFunction: "from:subtract:", arguments: [numbersExpr, avgExpr])
```

The built-in `from:subtract:` expects its arguments to be "two `NSExpression` objects representing numbers", but your first argument is an array.

`NSExpression`'s built-in functions aren't really designed for vector math. It might be possible to get what you're aiming for with `init(block:arguments:)`. However you wouldn't be able to use that with Core Data (not mentioned in your question, but you used the tag).